# Apps Script to set font for current selection in Google doc

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, text, fonts, google-docs

I have some Google Apps Script code to set the font of some text in a Google Document.

```
          text.setFontFamily(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "Roboto Mono");
```

But I want Roboto Mono *Medium*. How do I do this? I'm not sure what kind of entity *medium* is. I think it's a *weight*. But I don't see any documented way to set the weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I checked the font name by giving "Roboto Mono Medium", it's "Roboto Mono;500". So how about using `Roboto Mono;500` as the font name as follows?

#### From:

```
text.setFontFamily(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "Roboto Mono");
```

#### To:

```
text.setFontFamily(element.getStartOffset(), element.getEndOffsetInclusive(), "Roboto Mono;500");
```

#### Note:

- The simple sample script for checking the font name is as follows. When you use this, please copy and paste the script to the script editor of Google Document and selected a text on the body and run the script.

  ```
    const selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
    const text = selection.getSelectedElements()[0].getElement().asText();
    console.log(text.getFontFamily())  // Check the font name.
  ```

Comment: That works for me. Thanks! What do you mean when you said "checked the font name"? How do you "check" a font name?

Comment: @sigfpe  Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I added a sample script for checking the font name of the selected text. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I just seem to get nulls back from that code snippet using `getFontFamily`. I also tried `selection.getRangeElements()[0].getElement().asText()`. Still nulls.

Comment: @sigfpe Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about your new question, I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. Can you provide the detail information of your current situation? By this, I would like to try to understand about it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?